# How to avoid Selenium runtime exception UnreachableBrowserException

Tags: selenium, exception, webdriver, port

I am using Selenium with GhostDriver and sometimes I got the error:
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died., caused by exceptions include java.lang.InterruptedException
It happens when using findbyElement, findByElements, get, or click methods of Selenium.

It does not happens always and not in the same places, but it happens more frequently on Windows environments.

Does anyone knows how can I avoid this exception?

I tried adding more time while using waits but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this exception, you can override the get method. (Usually, this exception append once)

```
public class CustomPhantomJSDriver extends PhantomJSDriver {

    @Override
    public void get(String url) {
        int count = 0;
        int maxTries = 5;
        while (count < maxTries) {
            try {
                super.get(url);
                break;
            } catch (UnreachableBrowserException e) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count == maxTries) {
            throw new UnreachableBrowserException(url);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: http://matejtymes.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/webdriver-fix-for-unreachablebrowserexc.html

Use it anywhere you would otherwise use PhantomJSDriver (it covers all situations: get, click, findByElement, ...)

```
public class FixedPhantomJSDriver extends PhantomJSDriver {

    private final int retryCount = 2;

    public FixedPhantomJSDriver() {
    }

    public FixedPhantomJSDriver(Capabilities desiredCapabilities) {
        super(desiredCapabilities);
    }

    public FixedPhantomJSDriver(PhantomJSDriverService service, Capabilities desiredCapabilities) {
        super(service, desiredCapabilities);
    }

    @Override
    protected Response execute(String driverCommand, Map<String, ?> parameters) {
        int retryAttempt = 0;

        while (true) {
            try {

                return super.execute(driverCommand, parameters);

            } catch (UnreachableBrowserException e) {
                retryAttempt++;
                if (retryAttempt > retryCount) {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```